# Java, Check if a String is a palindrome. Case insensitive

Tags: java, string, compare

I want to write a java method to return true if a string is a palindrome.

Here is what I have so far:

```
String palindrome = "...";
boolean isPalindrome = palindrome.equals(
   new StringBuilder(palindrome).reverse().toString());
```

My problem with this is that it does not consider a word like: `Race car` to be a palindrome.

```
Doc, note, I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod.
```

What is the best way to test if this is a palindrome, with case insensitivity and ignoring punctuation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this regex to remove all punctuation and spaces and convert it to lower case

```
String palindrome = "..." // from elsewhere
boolean isPalindrome = palindrome.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").toLowerCase().equals(new StringBuilder(palindrome.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").toLowerCase()).reverse().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but:
Output:
Race car
false

Comment: @user2121604 - He just forgot to convert _palindrome_ to lowercase... You should try to understand and learn from this answer rather than just copying and pasting it.

Comment: Well I am trying to see if it works first and then try to learn from it.

But could you please elaborate? I don't get how to convert it all to lowercase, I am new to Java. Sorry about that, thanks

Comment: If you only want to match white space you can use \s instead of matching letter ranges, but it depends on how you want the specifics if the match to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean notPalindrome = false;
    String string = "Doc, note, I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod";

    string = string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","").toLowerCase();

    char[] array = string.toCharArray();
    for(int i=0, j=array.length-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
        if(array[i] != array[j]) {
            notPalindrome = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(string + " is palindrome? " + !notPalindrome);
}
```

Comment: Soln by Vineet seems more appropriate.

Comment: Actually this seems to work so far, I'll keep checking if anyone else has different ideas though before deciding to go for it!

Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

Use the below regex, to keep even `numeric` characters in the Palindrome, if needed. Else, you can just remove the `0-9` from the regex.

```
String palindrome = "..." // from elsewhere
String regex = "[^A-Za-z0-9]";
boolean isPalindrome = palindrome.equals(new StringBuilder(palindrome.replaceAll(regex, "").toLowerCase()).reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non `regex` solution.

```
public class so4
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String str = "Doc, note, I dissent. A fast never prevents a fatness. I diet on cod";
    char c[] =str.toCharArray();
    String newStr="";
    for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
    {
        if( (c[i]>=65 && c[i]<=90) || (c[i]>=97 && c[i]<=122))  //check ASCII values (A-Z 65-90) and (a-z 97-122)
        {
            newStr = newStr + c[i]; 
        }
    }
    boolean isPalindrome = newStr.toLowerCase().equals(new StringBuilder(newStr.toLowerCase()).reverse().toString());
    System.out.println(isPalindrome);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. convert to lower case
2. use a regex to remove everything but letters
3. reverse the string using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
4. compare the strings for equality

Code:

```
/**
 *  Returns true if s is a palindrome, ignoring whitespace
 *  punctuation, and capitalization.  Returns false otherwise.  
 */

public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    String forward = s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "");
    String reverse = new StringBuilder(forward).reverse().toString();
    return forward.equals(reverse);
}
```

For more info, see the documentation for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

- [String.toLowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29)
- [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)
- [StringBuilder.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29)

You can also find it by googling "*Java 7 String*" and clicking the first result.